# How to include static field without data from a dataset to carry it?

Tags: sql, ssrs-2012

I'm improving a report that currently uses a static table using the lookup function to fill its data from a few different datasets. We're pretty sure this is causing the report to take a lot longer to run, so I'm trying to use a table that uses column groups to achieve the same effect from a single dataset.

Here's what my query currently looks like. This functions exactly as I want it to as long as there's data.

```
Select CatName, CatCount, Category = 'Category 1', Sorting = 1
FROM
(Select CatName, Count(CatName) as CatCount FROM DataSet WHERE Parameters)

UNION

Select CatName, CatCount, Category = 'Category 2', Sorting = 2
FROM
(Select CatName, Count(CatName) as CatCount FROM DataSet WHERE Parameters)
```

When there are CatNames and CatCounts to pull from the select statement, the Category works and is pulled by the table as a column group. I need all of the groups to exist at all times.

However, sometimes we don't have data that fits the parameters for a category. The result when that happens is that there isn't a row for the Category field to use and that group doesn't exist in the table. Is there any way I can force the Category field to exist regardless of the data?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly, then you may be able to use [ISNULL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/isnull-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017).  ISNULL returns either the value you were for which you were looking (check_expression) or the alternative (replacement_value) if check_expression is NULL.

*ISNULL ( check_expression , replacement_value )*

```
Select CatName, CatCount, Category = 'Category 2', Sorting = 2
FROM
(Select isnull(CatName,""), Count(CatName) as CatCount FROM DataSet WHERE Parameters)
```

**EDIT**
How about a left outer join?

```
Select b.CatName, b.CatCount, Category = 'Category 2', Sorting = 2
FROM
(select '' as CatName, 0 as Catcount) a left outer join  (Select CatName, Count(CatName) as CatCount FROM DataSet WHERE Parameters) b on a.CatName = b.CatName
```

Comment: Not quite what the issue was. I edited my question to be more clear about it. The issue isn't that the data doesn't exist in the database, but that the parameters are filtering out the data that is there.

Comment: the `LEFT JOIN` is still the way to go though. Get a list of all categories then left join to your current filtered results and if the filters filtered everything out you'll just have the categories with no joined data which sound like what you want.

Answer (score -1):

Found a solution. Took a few tries, not the prettiest, and we'll have to see if it actually improves performance, but it works the way we wanted. Generalized code:

```
Select C.CatName, C.CatCount, Category = 'Category 1', Sorting = 1
FROM
(Select Top 5 B.CatName, Count(B.CatName) as CatCount
FROM
(Select CatName = case when CatOnlyParam in (Category1Filter) then A.CatName else NULL end
FROM
(Select CatName FROM DataSet WHERE GeneralParameters) as A
) as B
order by CatCount
) as C

UNION

etc
```

Separating the parameters into different steps guarantees that there will be values for each category, even if those values are NULL. I'm sure there's a cleaner way to get the same effect, but this functions.

Working from the inside out:

Stage 1 (Select statement A): Selects the value from the dataset with very general parameters (between a start and end date, resolved or not, etc).

Stage 2 (Select statement B): Uses the case statement to only pull the data that is relevant for this department while leaving behind NULLs for the data that isn't.

Stage 3 (Select statement C): Takes the data from the list of names and NULLs and gets a count from it. Sorts by that count and takes the top 5. If a category has no data, then the nulls will get "counted" to 0 and passed on to the final step.

Stage 4 (Final select statement): Adds the static fields to the information from the previous step. A category without data will get passed to this as:

```
CatName: NULL
CatCount: 0
Category: "Category 1"
Sorting: 1
```

Then this is repeated for the other categories and UNION'd together. Any suggestions to improve this are more than welcome.